# Calculating percentage

Tags: macros, calculations

I have tried to use the `calc` package to write a macro which prints a percentage based on two numbers. E.g.: `\printpercent{100}{200}` should display 50% as 100 is the half-way point of 200. I have tried many different combinations, but cannot seem to get any meaningful answers printed. See below, for just one of the many formulas I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{z}
\newcommand{\printpercent}[2]{%
    \setcounter{z}{#1 / #2 * 100}
    $#1/#2*100=\arabic{z}\%$
}%
\begin{document}
    \printpercent{1}{100}
    \printpercent{250}{200}
\end{document}
```

That prints out:

> 1/100*100 = 0%
>
> 250/200*100 = 100%

- How can I calculate a percent from these numbers?

Comment: Is the input always integer values? What sort of range of input needs to work? Are you looking for accuracy to whole percentage points or more than that?

Comment: All of the numbers are integers. For the time being, I only need between 1 and 1 million, but for the future, might need to calculate in with numbers up to 1 billion. Sometimes, I only need to show a rounded whole number. In certain situations, I may need to display 1 decimal places.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The calculation are for intergers only. You should multiply `#1` by 100 first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{z}
\newcommand{\printpercent}[2]{%
    \setcounter{z}{#1 * 100 / #2}
    $#1/#2*100=\arabic{z}\%$
}%
\begin{document}
    \printpercent{1}{100}
    \printpercent{250}{200}
\end{document}
```

And it is easier to use eTeX:

```
\newcommand\printpercent[2]{\the\numexpr#1*100/#2\%}
```

If you need more precise solution, or the input is not interger values, you can use `fp`, `fltpoint`, `pgfmath` or `l3fp` packages for this. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand\printpercent[2]{\FPeval\result{round(#1*100/#2,1)}\result\%}
\begin{document}
    \printpercent{2.3}{100}
    \printpercent{176.5}{190.375}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use `pgfmath` with `siunitx`. I'm not sure that the precision is always correct, in this case it's possible to use `fpu`or `fp`.

**update** :
 For a user who works with `tikz` it's possible to replace `SI` by `\pgfmathprintnumber`

```
\documentclass{article} 

\input{pgfutil-common.tex}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfmath}  
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\printpercent}[3][2]{%  
    \pgfmathdivide{#2}{#3}% 
    \pgfmathmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{100}%
    \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=#1]{\pgfmathresult}{\percent}
}%

\begin{document}    
     \printpercent[0]{1}{100}   
     \printpercent{200}{250}   
     \printpercent{2}{3}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Was that the intention of the `siunitx` package to place a space between the number and percent symbol?